# Installing VirtualBox on Linux BASH shell for Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Windows 10 computer with developer mode enabled and BASH subsystem installed.  It has worked well so far on basic commands.  I have also discovered that you can find the windows "C" drive at `/mnt/c` which makes sense.  I've also been able to do a successful install of Vagrant by the command

```
sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

HOWEVER, Vagrant of course requires VirtualBox, which I installed on my Windows machine, BUT I learned the hard way that the Linux kernel can't "see" or use that.

So the question is, how do I install VirtualBox on my Linux kernel?  The support I've seen on the VirtualBox site deals with installing drivers for the UI, and I don't want that.  I am thinking there is a corresponding apt-get install for VirtualBox.

Comment: You don't have linux kernel, only a native bash.

Comment: Run `apt-cache search virtualbox` and have a look whenever a package is available.

Answer (score 1):

So actually, it was as simple as entering

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

On the BASH shell, which successfully installed it.